# Loading local HTML Slow when Internet Available

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am loading locally stored HTML and JS pages into a WKWebView.  However, when the device's internet is enabled, the page loads take a very long time.  If I put the device into airplane mode, the same pages load very quickly.

To get the page I am using the following static method:

```
static func getURLForPage(_ pageName:String)->URL
{
   return Bundle.main.url(forResource: pageName, withExtension: "html")!
}
```

To load the content into a WKWebView I am using:

```
self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: FileServer.getURLForPage(self.menuName)))
```

This issue occurs on actual devices as well as the simulator.

Comment: Two thoughts: does the behaviour change if you set a base URL in this call? Second, is there a reason you don't want to use the loadHTMLString function?

Comment: Where does baseURL fit into these function calls?  Also, not sure why I'd want to read the html into a string and then into the web page rather than directly from the file?

Comment: The base URL can be specified in order to help the wkwebview resolve relative URLs in the html. See the introductory documentation. See https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview/1415011-load. Not sure about your aversion to loadhtmlString. You are going to have to load the HTML into the WKWebview one way or another! Works very well in my experience.